# Multiple ajax request every second

Tags: jquery, ajax

Basically, I want to use setTimeout to the following code such that response() will be called every second.

```
$(function(){
    var x = $('#front');
    var y = $('#back');
    var z = $('#side');
    $.when( $.ajax( "/front" ), $.ajax( "/back" ),$.ajax( "/side" ) ).done(response);
        function response( res1,res2,res3 ) {
        x.val(res1);
        y.val(res2);
        z.val(res3);
      }
});
```

Sorry for the mistake as I'm noob to this topic...

Comment: you want the setTimeout once all the ajax requests are resolved?

Comment: yes after after all ajax req

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Promise` and `setTimeout` in order to achieve what you are looking for. Look the below code for reference.

```js
var promiseOneSecond = function(res) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function(){
      resolve(res)
    }, 1000)
  })
}

promiseOneSecond('res1')
.then(function(res) {
  console.log(': ', res);
  return promiseOneSecond('res2');
})
.then(function(res) {
  console.log(': ', res);
  return promiseOneSecond('res3');
})
.then(function(res) {
  console.log(': ', res);
})
```